# Set an attribute for a Rails record in a loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I have a model `User`. I want a function that sets the attribute `emotion` to equal `happy` for each user record.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :emotion


  def self.add_a_happy_emotion
    users = User.all

    users.each do |user|
      user.emotion = "happy"
    end

    users
  end
end
```

When I call `> User.add_a_happy_emotion` in my console, the users do not have any `emotion` attribute. They will only have the default model attributes. Will an attribute not be set if it is called in a do loop? Or is this related to attr_accessor? Or maybe am I missing something else?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Rails 4. `User.all` will return an active record relation and not an array.

So you will have to modify your code to get users will updated attribute.

```
  def self.add_a_happy_emotion
    users = User.all

    result_users = users.map do |user|
      user.emotion = "happy"
      user
    end

    result_users
  end
```

Comment: User.all will return a Relationship but when he iterates using each, the query hits the DB. So his is a normal use. Also when you use map you should be using each, so you don't need to return users. map() is to change the format of the result of the iteration.

Answer (score 0):

may be it is returning the cached copy. How about this

```
def self.add_a_happy_emotion
    users = User.all

    users.each do |user|
      user.emotion = "happy"
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

2 problems with it:

1 - Your **attr_accessor** is overriding Rails'. You really don't need it in Rails. Just put the attributes of your model in the migration and you'll be alright.

2 - If you modify the user objects and don't save them, the changes will never be persisted. You can use **update_attribute** for this purpose.

So you'll end up with something like:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  #no more attr_accessor here

  def self.add_a_happy_emotion
    users = User.all

    users.each do |user|
      user.update_attribute(:emotion, "happy") #this persists the entities to the DB
    end

  end
end
```